# File size exceeding defined limit in Hadoop local.cache.size

Tags: caching, bigdata, hadoop2

In my cluster I have defined local.cache.size to 10 GB, but I have seen some file with size of around 24GB. I am failed to understand why it increased the defined limit . The size limit is done at the initial installation of cluster.

Can anyone know about the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

In hadoop2.0 it is removed and has no effect:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7184